# Conditional formatting, entire row based, apply to other worksheets - Excel 2010

Tags: excel, row, conditional-formatting, worksheet

I currently have a spreadsheet that has conditional formatting to change the colors of the rows, from column A-L, based upon the value of column "D" (Pending and Active change to yellow, Scheduled and Forwarded change to green, and Discontinued and Cancelled change to red).

I however have several worksheets in this once excel document which I would like to extend the same rules to. Is there a way to apply these rules to the other worksheets in the doc, or will I have to manually enter them for each doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a single rule apply to several sheets does not seem to be possible.

Source: http://excelribbon.tips.net/T003433_Applying_Conditional_Formatting_to_Multiple_Worksheets.html

It could be possible, however, to copy a conditional formatting rule you have set for one sheet to another (see link). The link's suggestions include

- **copying the conditional formatting** - select the formatted cells in original sheet; click the Format Painter (on the Home tab of the ribbon); switch to the target worksheet; select the cells to which the formatting should be applied
- **macro recorder** - run the macro recorder while setting up the conditional formatting; re-run the macro as you display each of your other worksheets. Detailed instructions:

  - go to View->Macros->Record Macro-OK
  - now add your conditional formatting rules to the current worksheet
  - go to View->Macros->Stop Recording
  - now you can switch to any sheet and apply the same formatting rules by executing your macro (View->Macros->View Macros->Run)

Comment: I have other individual formats, such as cell width and height and date vs text for each worksheet. Is there any way to only copy over the conditional formatting rules?

Comment: Yes, you could do that using the macro recorder option.
I added a step-by-step guide to the above answer. Also, please accept the answer if you feel it solves your question.